# Generalized roots of a polynomial.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, roots

Define $c$ to be the generalized $i$-th root of polynomial $f(x_1, ..., x_n)$ over a field $\mathscr{F}$ to be value such that $f(x_1, ..., c, ..., x_n) = 0$ where we substituted $x_i = c$.

Note that if $c$ is a generalized $i$-th root of $f$, then it can be written as $h(x_1, ..., x_n)(x_i-c)$, and that if $f$ is a non-zero polynomial, it can have at most $\text{deg}(f)$ generalized roots.

Is there a name for generalized roots? This one I made up.

Comment: To check what I'm thinking, does $ f(x,y) = x^2 + y^2 + 1$ have any generalized roots? It seems to be no, because $f(X,y)$ and $f(x,Y)$ are never the constant 0 function.

Comment: @Calvin We'd like to distinguish between polynomials and polynomial functions. Here $f(x, c) = f(c, x) = x^2+c^2+1$ is a polynomial of degree $2$, hence non-zero.

Comment: As in, can you give an explicit example of a polynomial with a generalized root? It seems to me that these are merely the "variable separable/factorable" parts

Comment: @Calvin $x^3+xy^2+x^2+x+1+y^2$

Comment: What is the generalized i-th root for that polynomial?

Comment: I am looking for a name. This clearly generalizes roots and some of the properties from case $n=1$

Comment: Sorry, it's not "clearly" to me, which is why I'm asking for an explicit example. Please state it out in full, and even ideally add it to your statement.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118015/discussion-between-jakobian-and-calvin-lin).